# How to upgrade HBOOT from 0.80.0007 to 1.01.0001

Tags: bootloader, htc-wildfire

I own an HTC Wildfire with HBOOT version 0.80.0007 and S-On. How do I upgrade to HBOOT 1.01.0001? Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction? I've been racking my brains for the last few days, looking for a useful tutorial, with no luck at all, I hope to sort my problem out.

Comment: I think you need to flash your SPL first. The `S-on` thing might prevent you from upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

It was enough flashing the device with [RUU_Buzz_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.22.405.1_Radio_13.55.55.24H_3.35.20.10_release_160191_signed.exe](http://www.shipped-roms.com/download.php?category=android&model=Buzz&file=RUU_Buzz_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.22.405.1_Radio_13.55.55.24H_3.35.20.10_release_160191_signed.exe)

Comment: For non-Windows users, a recent radio image (`buzz.radio-3.35.20.10-signed.zip`) can be found in [this XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=24259864&postcount=3). Seems to be the same version (note the `3.35.20.10` in both filenames).